# Each react view calling the server for info, the right approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

I'm new to react and I'm building a task list app that has a page showing a list of categories of tasks (Category Page), another page showing a list of tasks for a category (TaskList Page), a page showing more details about a task (TaskDetails Page). Just an application that can help me grasp the concepts of using the MERN stack.

I have a layout and the category, tasklist  and taskdetails pages are not children of each other so they can't pass props to each other and I need the data of all tasks in a category to be shown on the tasklist page and details on a task to be shown on the task details page.

Right now I've been able to use redux to fetch all the details from the DB through the server on the start of the application, but the problem is when a user navigates directly to a task, for example, let's say the link is shareable and the user navigates to that link, all data in the redux store is gone and I then need to fetch the data again from the DB. I know I can persist the store data to LocalStorage or a client storage, but I'm assuming the data is not meant to be public in this case (just to learn how to deal with private data), so I can't store them in client storage as everyone will have access to view it, that's why i keep fetching from server if state is gone.

If this application grows and a user has like a 1000+ tasks per category (just an example), my thoughts are that trips to the server are going to be more time consuming, when on each refresh the application has to reload all the data, and the initial data loading also, might be too large to load at start of the app and may cause a delay.

Does it make sense to let each page call the server for the data it needs or should i continue with this load all at startup approach?

Btw I'm using embedded structure in mongo to store the tasklist in a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library to handle persistence of your data to local storage for this you can use:

[redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

after wards you can use other libraries for encrypting the data present on local storage for this you can use:

[redux-persist-transform-encrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist-transform-encrypt)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like this idea, but is it okay to pull all the data at initial startup or let each page make request to the server for the data it needs to render? Assuming the data in the DB is large.